# Do Ultra-dense H11-grade HEPA filters remove up to 99% of PM0.3 particles?

Tags: environmental-health, pollution

The Xaiomi Air Purifier 2 [website](http://www.mi.com/en/air/filter/) claims:

> HEPA (High-efficiency Particulate Arrestance) is frequently used in hospitals and labs to filter out micron-sized particles. Mi Air Purifier uses an ultra-dense Toray PP and PET HEPA filter to trap PM2.5, PM0.3, pollen and other inhalable particles, allowing only clean air to pass through. It measures 7.7m when fully extended and **effectively filters out 99% of PM0.3 particles** and 99.99% of PM2.5 particles.

Is that part of the claim true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [2005 Deparment of Energy standard on HEPA Filters](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwj7tbjP44XRAhUn44MKHdGBANAQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fenergy.gov%2Fsites%2Fprod%2Ffiles%2F2013%2F06%2Ff1%2Fdoe-std-3020-2005.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGTsFEzUcYxvd4YNfOrISMOpavBng&cad=rja]):

> 5.2 **Performance Requirements:** Mandatory performance requirements for HEPA
>   filters are set out below. These performance requirements shall be demonstrated by
>   test and inspection by the manufacturer. These performance requirements shall also be demonstrated by test and inspection by the FTF when applicable (see Section 4.1).
>
> 5.2.1 **Penetration:** Aerosol penetration for any HEPA filter shall not exceed
>   0.03% (0.0003) at 0.3 micrometer particle size.

And then from the [2015 Standard](https://energy.gov/sites/prod/files/2015/06/f23/DOE-STD-3020-2015.pdf):

> High Efficiency Particulate Air (HEPA) Filter: A throwaway, extended-medium, dry type
>   filter with a rigid casing enclosing the full depth of the pleats. The filter shall exhibit a
>   minimum efficiency of 99.97% when tested with an aerosol of 0.3 micrometer diameter.

It seems like the requirement for particulate of 0.3 micrometers(PM0.3) at 99.97% must be met in order for a filter to qualify as a HEPA filter. This would exceed the the original claim for only 99% thus validating it.

**So if you have an approved HEPA filter, then the standard guarantees the 99.97% for 0.3 micrometer diameter particles.**

I do remember seeing that this standard is for DOE contractors. Consumer product qualifications may be held to a lower standard. I don't know.